# What are LDTR and GDTR?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, intel, cpu-registers

I know what paging and segmentation are, but, I cannot find an explanation for those two registers, present in Intel x86 architecture. Could anyone clarify me what is the purpose of those registers, why do processors need them?

Comment: They store the starting point for the segment descriptor tables. Otherwise the cpu wouldn't know where to find them. See section 2.4 MEMORY-MANAGEMENT REGISTERS in the system programming guide.

Comment: GDTR is the GDT (Global Descriptor Table) Register. It contains the base address (linear) and limit for the GDT, and is set using [`lgdt`](https://ulukai.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insLGDT). LDTR is the LDT (Local Descriptor Table) Register and contains the linear base address and limit for the LDT. However, [`lldt`](https://ulukai.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insLGDT) takes a selector as input (which must point into the GDT), not the plain base and limit.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the ldt, and why the selector must point into the GDT, please? Also, what is their purpose? Why is there a need for both gdt and ldt, which information is considered to be global and local?

Comment: You need to read up on how segmentation is handled if you don't know what the purpose of the GDT and LDT is. And not just Real/Virtual 86 Mode segmentation but Protected Mode / Long Mode segmentation too.

Comment: Then, suggest me some papers. I am a beginner to this topic. I know how virtualization works, I know what segmentation is, but I don't know what are those registers.

Comment: Intel's manuals would be the obvious place to look, or https://wiki.osdev.org/LDT.  Hint: a bit in a segment selector tells the CPU whether to index the IDT or LDT with it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Got a typo there, you meant "to index the GDT or LDT with it". IDT is another thing.